# How to turn dataframe rows into multiindex levels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
ID ; name; location; level; DATE19970901; DATE19970902; ...;DATE20201031;survey;person
001;  foo;     east;   500;        123.1;        342.5; ...;       234.5;     A;  John
002;  bar;     west;    50;         67.8;         98.3; ...;        76.6;     A;  Jenn
003;  baz;    north;  5000;        535.7;         99.9; ...;       432.6;     B;  John
```

which I need to turn into a dataframe like this:

```
ID         001    002   003
name       foo    bar   baz
location   east   west  north
level      500    50    5000
survey     A      A     B
person     John   Jenn  John
date
1997-09-01 123.1  67.8  535,7 
1991-09-02 342.5  98.3  99.9
...
2020-10-31 234.5  76.6  432.6
```

Now the easiest way seems to me to read it in, `.transpose()` it and then tell it to turn the data rows 0,1,2,8443,8444 into multiindex rows, but I'm missing a function for it. [`.MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame) does only seem to take a complete df to turn into a multiindex. I could probably split my df into a multiindex df and a data df and merge them, but that seems complicated and error prone to me.

What's an easy way to do it, is to read in the csv, transpose the df, export it to csv and read that in again, but that seems rather hacky (and slow, though that is not really an issue in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a transposition, with identification of the non-DATE columns, and conversion `to_datetime`:

```
# read dataset as semicolon-separated data, ignoring spaces
df = pd.read_csv('inpt_data.csv', sep=r'\s*;\s*', engine='python')

# identify non-DATE columns
cols = list(df.columns.difference(list(df.filter(like='DATE')), sort=False))
# or if you already know the columns:
# cols = ['ID', 'name', 'location', 'level', 'survey', 'person']

# reshape, convert to dates
out = df.set_index(cols).T.rename_axis('date')
out.index = pd.to_datetime(out.index, format='DATE%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
ID              1     2      3
name          foo   bar    baz
location     east  west  north
level        500   50     5000
survey          A     A      B
person       John  Jenn   John
date                          
1997-09-01  123.1  67.8  535.7
1997-09-02  342.5  98.3   99.9
2020-10-31  234.5  76.6  432.6
```

Comment: Looks good. Of course it doesn't work with my real data, but I guess that's probably my (or my datas) fault. I'll accept the answer when I've figured it out that the issue really is my side.

Comment: @JC_CL you can update the question with your real dataset (or a more realistic mockup), what doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I had an unnamed (i.e. `''`) column in the original data, which got turned into `Unnamed: 0` when reading it in, which of course was not in my original list of `cols` (I opted for the hand written list, since filtering for `DATE` also caught a multiindex level containing that word.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you already have a list of non-date columns then you could directly use `out = pd.read_csv('inpt_data.csv', sep=r'\s*;\s*', engine='python', index_col=cols).T ; out.index = pd.to_datetime(out.index, format='DATE%Y%m%d')`